# Get a JSON of my FormType schema

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'm trying to generate a JSON of my form type in my controller using [liform](https://github.com/Limenius/Liform) or [liform-bundle](https://github.com/Limenius/LiformBundle) but got the error :

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getBlockPrefix" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy"." at /home/admin/Documents/displayce/code/vendor/limenius/liform/src/Limenius/Liform/FormUtil.php line 39

the code in my controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $entity, array(
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'csrf_protection' => false, 
    ));
$schema = json_encode($this->get('liform')->transform($form));
```

My form type code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('startDate', 'date', array(
            'label' => 'Start Date',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'input' => 'datetime',
        ))
        ->add('endDate', 'date', array(
            'label' => 'End Date (included)',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'input' => 'datetime',
        ))
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Name',
            'max_length' => 255,
        ))
        ->add('budget', 'money', array(
            'label' => 'Budget (target)',
            'required' => true,
            'scale' => 0, // not showing decimals
        ))
        ->add('target', 'targeting', array(
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
}
```

and the targeting type :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('contexts', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Context(s)',
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Context',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('contextDetails', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Detailed Context(s)',
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ContextDetail',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'group_by' => 'context.name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('dataVariables', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Variable',
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\DataVariable',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'group_by' => function($dataVariable, $key, $index) {
                return $dataVariable->getDataProvider()->getName();
            }
        ))

        // Include criteria
        ->add('region', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Region(s)',
            'choices' => RegionDepartment::$regions,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('department', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Department(s)',
            'choices' => RegionDepartment::$departments,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ))
    ;
```

It might be because I use a nested formtype ?

My goal if **to combine symfony FormType with React Component** so as long as you can redirect me to a solution to do that, i will me glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked the bundle to change ->getBlockPrefix to ->getName() since the first one is not in Form.php in Symfony 2.7

Answer (score 0):

add a getBlockPrefix to your formType and targeting type like this :

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
   return 'name of your form type';
}
```

Comment: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getBlockPrefix" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form"."

I don't have the function in Form.php so I cannot access it

Comment: I'm using symfony 2.7, Is it a function I will have in a more recent version or I had in an older one ?